# Child Width Calculation standard?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My question is so simple but rather problematic for me, if a parent div have padding and child's div width is 100%, child's div width is always shorter than its parent one. if i change child div as absolute div and parent div as relative, child's width is just equal to the parent's no matter padding and margin in parents. Like this:

```css
.first {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10%;
  position: relative;
}

.second {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">HI
  <div class="second">
    HELLO
  </div>
</div>
```

Eventhough parent's position is totally relative, so you assume Child is totally dependent on '.first'div. So, I am assuming how is child width is calculated in this case?

Comment: for position:absolute the reference is the padding box unlike other element which is content-box

Answer (score 1):

When you set child div to position absolute (and parent has position relative value), then this element is removed from the normal document flow. Also, **if left property is set other than 'auto'** it is normal to "ignore" the padding because according to W3C [docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#propdef-position) "These properties specify offsets with respect to the box's containing block" (if it's auto then it shouldn't ignore padding, but width: 100% will "ignore" padding and when parent has 100px then child also will have 100% width.). See also this for answer what is a containing block - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block.